# Facebook Blackberry SDK Error 500

Tags: java, facebook, blackberry

I am trying to create application in BlackBerry that connect to Facebook using **facebook-bb-sdk-0.8.25** . First time I used it, it ran well for a few days. But since 5 days ago, after coming into login page, the response returns no **access_token** or **auth_token** and I got **Error 500**.

I have tried to find the solution [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Facebook-SDK-problems/td-p/730881) but still not resolve my problem. I don't know what is wrong with this application codes or the Facebook services? Somebody got the same problem or the solution please discuss here. Thank you

After Login page, its showing the following error -

> Error 500 
> The server encountered an internal error and could not meet
> your request.
>
> - Inform the Webmaster of the problem site(s).
>
> Try Again

Comment: iam facing the same problem. But didnt get any solutios yet....

Comment: Same problem on this side. I have a suspicion that something on the fb side changed and the BB SDK has not been updated. Honestly I doubt it ever will be. Will update if I find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem solved now. Facebook solved the problem. You can now use the same facebook jar file. Its working properly now.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried it, it works fine now.