# Error with Facebook Integration on blackberry

Tags: facebook, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am trying to integrate Facebook with my BlackBerry app by using the jars from the `facebook-bb-sdk` project on Sourceforge. When I open my application and click on the Facebook button to login with Facebook, it successfully opens the Facebook login page. But after that when I enter the username and password and click on login it 
me some error as shown in the figure below.

"**Error**"
**"Display one of the following values `async`,`iframe`,`page`,`popup`,`touch`"**

Now when I click on OK button I get a screen with success written on the left top corner. After that nothing will happen. Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181928/facebook-blackberry-sdk-error-500

Comment: all BB developers facing the same problem

Comment: if you will get this solution please let me know.I am also getting problem since 5 days..

Comment: I posted an answer a while back, for fb integration on bb. It was working for me, but the user asking had issues with user agent settings. Take a look, maybe it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138488/fb-sdk-not-working-on-os-7/24159292#24159292